# Multicell overvoltage protection with op amps, how to get rid of oscillating behavior?

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, oscillation, over-voltage-protection

Still a beginner in analog electronics, so excuse me for  being inaccurate. Also I am playing with circuitjs@falstad.com which might not be the most accurate sim...

I wanted to provide a very sharp overvoltage threshold, while being able to stack more cells in series. So I went with a bypass MOSFET controlled by a couple of op amps: the first sensing the voltage and the second comparing it to a reference.

[image]

The circuit appears to work fine, clamping the 1 mF capacitor at 2.7 V. However as soon as I swapped the ideal op amps with LM741, I started to get wide voltage swings at the MOSFET gate and, in turn, large currents in and out the capacitor.

Where are these coming from? Can they be mitigated? I put a low pass filter at the gate which improved the situation, but can the source be addressed directly? ...or is it just a bad design?

- [Here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000001%202.3728258192205156%2036%205%2050%0Ac%20768%20512%20768%20384%200%200.001%20-2.603260676835325%0Af%20944%20448%20896%20448%2032%203%2020%0Aw%20672%20544%20768%20544%200%0Ag%20608%20544%20608%20576%200%0Aw%20672%20544%20608%20544%200%0Ar%201040%20512%201136%20512%200%20100000%0Ar%201008%20432%201008%20384%200%20100000%0Ar%20912%20512%201040%20512%200%20100000%0Ar%20944%20384%201008%20384%200%20100000%0AO%201232%20384%201280%20384%201%0Aw%20768%20384%20816%20384%200%0Ap%20816%20384%20816%20512%201%200%0AR%201136%20368%201136%20320%200%200%2040%202.7%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20672%20384%20672%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20768%20384%20672%20384%200%0Aw%20816%20384%20896%20384%200%0Aw%20896%20432%20896%20384%200%0Aw%20816%20512%20896%20512%200%0Aw%201232%20240%20944%20240%200%0Ai%20608%20544%20608%20384%200%201%0Aw%20944%20448%20944%20240%200%0A409%201040%20400%201136%20400%203%200.6%20-16.983486770768266%200.023100000000000002%200%0AR%201088%20368%201088%20288%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%201136%20512%201136%20400%200%0Aw%201040%20512%201040%20416%200%0A409%201136%20384%201232%20384%201%200.6%20-16.74768480755588%200.023100000000000002%200%0Aw%201232%20384%201232%20240%200%0AR%201184%20352%201184%20288%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20944%20384%20896%20384%200%0Ag%201008%20432%201008%20464%200%0Aw%201040%20384%201008%20384%200%0Aw%20896%20512%20912%20512%200%0Aw%20768%20512%20816%20512%200%0Aw%20896%20464%20896%20512%200%0Aw%20768%20512%20768%20544%200%0AR%201088%20432%201088%20464%200%200%2040%20-15%200%200%200.5%0AR%201184%20416%201184%20464%200%200%2040%20-15%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20672%20384%20608%20384%200%0Ao%200%2032%200%204099%2020%201638.4%200%202%200%203%0A) is the circuit in the picture above
- [Here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2019.867427341514983%2050%205%2050%0Ac%20768%20448%20768%20384%200%200.001%20-3.2001136194528765%0Af%201008%20416%20912%20416%2032%201.5%2020%0Aw%20768%20544%20768%20448%200%0Aw%20672%20544%20768%20544%200%0Ag%20672%20544%20672%20576%200%0AO%20608%20192%20560%20192%201%0Aw%20672%20544%20608%20544%200%0Ag%201088%20336%201088%20352%200%0Ar%201040%20448%201136%20448%200%20100000%0Ar%201040%20336%201040%20384%200%20100000%0Ar%20912%20448%201040%20448%200%20100000%0Ar%20912%20384%201040%20384%200%20100000%0Aw%201136%20400%201136%20448%200%0AO%201232%20384%201280%20384%201%0Aw%20768%20448%20816%20448%200%0Aw%20768%20384%20816%20384%200%0Aw%201232%20384%201232%20496%200%0Aa%201040%20400%201136%20400%209%2015%20-15%201000000%201.6000248092302538%201.6000568097264383%20100000%0Aw%201040%20448%201040%20416%200%0Aw%201088%20336%201040%20336%200%0Ap%20816%20384%20816%20448%201%200%0AR%201296%20144%201360%20144%200%200%2040%203.2%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20672%20192%20672%20544%200%201000%0Aw%20768%20192%20672%20192%200%0Aw%201296%20144%201296%20336%200%0Aw%201136%20368%201136%20336%200%0Aw%201136%20336%201296%20336%200%0Aw%20816%20384%20912%20384%200%0Aw%20912%20400%20912%20384%200%0Aw%20816%20448%20912%20448%200%0Aw%20912%20432%20912%20448%200%0Ar%20672%20192%20608%20192%200%2010%0Aa%201136%20384%201232%20384%208%2015%200%201000000%203.2%203.2000496184605063%20100000%0A174%20960%20496%201056%20416%201%20100000%200.32180000000000003%20Resistance%0Aw%201232%20496%201056%20496%200%0Ai%20608%20544%20608%20192%200%200.1%0Aw%201232%20304%201056%20304%200%0Aa%201136%20192%201232%20192%208%2015%200%201000000%203.2%203.2000507334103627%20100000%0Aw%201136%20144%201296%20144%200%0Aw%201136%20176%201136%20144%200%0Ap%20816%20192%20816%20256%201%200%0Aw%201088%20144%201040%20144%200%0Aw%201040%20256%201040%20224%200%0Aa%201040%20208%201136%20208%209%2015%20-15%201000000%203.2000821764316183%203.2001141769389525%20100000%0Aw%201232%20192%201232%20304%200%0Aw%20768%20192%20816%20192%200%0Aw%20768%20256%20816%20256%200%0AO%201232%20192%201280%20192%201%0Aw%201136%20208%201136%20256%200%0Ar%201040%20144%201040%20192%200%20100000%0Ar%201040%20256%201136%20256%200%20100000%0Ag%201088%20144%201088%20160%200%0Aw%20768%20384%20768%20256%200%0Ac%20768%20256%20768%20192%200%200.001%20-3.2001147344250294%0A174%20960%20304%201056%20224%201%20100000%200.9455000000000001%20Resistance%0Aw%20912%20240%20912%20256%200%0Aw%20816%20256%20912%20256%200%0Aw%20912%20208%20912%20192%200%0Aw%20816%20192%20912%20192%200%0Ar%20912%20192%201040%20192%200%20100000%0Ar%20912%20256%201040%20256%200%20100000%0Af%201008%20224%20912%20224%2032%201.5%2020%0Ag%20960%20304%20960%20320%200%0Ag%20960%20496%20960%20512%200%0Ao%200%2032%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%200%202%200%203%0A) is my initial attempt, with two cells in series and ideal op amps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the real opamps you used in the circuit are going unstable. This could be due to a phase margin that is unacceptable. You basically have two series opamps and a MOSFET in a control loop and this can easily go unstable. A single opamp with local feedback can easily be made to go unstable (how you make an oscillator) so your configuration is likely to be problematic.

> I put a low pass filter at the gate which improved the situation,

This can be a useful trick to remedy unstable circuits. It’s called “introducing a dominant pole”.

> But can the source be addressed directly?

The “source” is the target circuit that you have evolved and is a common problem facing analogue circuit designers. There’s probably nothing much you can change in your circuit so, you add a dominant pole!

One thought, you should probably add A resistor in series with the source of the MOSFET. This can reduce gain dramatically and needn’t be a hindrance to correct circuit operation. Decide what value you could tolerate when trying to balance cells and put it in place. It’s probably a good idea anyway because you don’t want the MOSFET turning fully on under any circumstances.

One last thing. Don’t use 741s; they are such dinosaurs and have poor performance compared to more modern devices. Even the LM324 (despite its age) is a superior choice.